# EditText в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Если добавляю  `EditText`  в `ExpandableListView`  в  `item`, который на верхнем уровне, то перестает работать выпадающий список по нажатию на этот  `item`. Как-то можно сделать, что б выпадающий список продолжал дальше работать? Или в  `ExpandableListView` нельзя добавлять `EditText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно отключить фокусировку EditText и включать на время ввода текста:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        return false;
    }
});
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        editText.setFocusable(false);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    }
});
```

Но всё-таки вместо EditText лучше сделать TextView и Button/ImageButton, по нажатию которого вызывать диалог редактирования текста. Только не забудьте у Button `android:focusable="false"` поставить, иначе тоже не будет раскрываться ExpandableListView.

Comment: помогло, но, наверное, действительно лучше сделать TextView